# How to add a simple ESD protection to RDA5807M FM tuner antenna pin?

Tags: rf, antenna, esd, frequency-modulation, ham-radio

I am using an i2c controlled FM tuner IC (RDA5807M) in a DIY fm radio, but I am a little bit worried about ESD protection on the Antenna line (A headphone lead being used for this). Can i add standard 1n4148 diodes for this purpose? There will not be any strong human body ESD because i live in a quite hot and humid country, so just basic protection will do. I want to achieve this using standard parts only and not some specialised TVS diode or fancy ESD protection diodes. I want to know if there will be any signal attenuation due to the stray capacitance of 1n4148 diodes (3pF max, according to datasheet) or its leakage currents. I have attached the relevant part of my circuit diagram. Datasheet of the FM tuner IC - https://cxem.net/tuner/files/tuner84_RDA5807M_datasheet_v1.pdf

[image: Is this ESD protection implementation correct?]

Comment: why dont u use tvs diode ? https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/esdalc12-1t2.pdf more adapted for ESD protection. your switching diode 1N4148 is not enough!

Comment: I've never seen 1N4148 diodes used as ESD protection for FM antennas or other RF applications. And I wouldn't rely on 1N4148 for these purposes. Instead, I'd prefer low capacitance (<1pF) ESD diodes (e.g. [this one](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/ESD8472-D.PDF)).

Comment: i understand that 4148 will not give adequate protection against ESD. Can you tell me if it will cause any rf signal attenuation in the FM band?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need additional protection.
The radio input is [protected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt2UE.jpg) if you do not have an outdoor antenna.

Comment: The word is "capacitance".

Comment: No this will not be an outdoor device. it will be a small battery powered radio, with the earphone leads used as an antenna. Do i still need to add TVS diodes? will 1n4148 cause problems with reception? or attenuate FM signal?

Comment: @aditya444 Of course, this does not require any additional protection. The radio input is [protected](https://imgur.com/a/7U3LE2Y) if you do not have an outdoor antenna.

Comment: @csabahu Oh dear god I totally missed that diagram in the datasheet. Thank you. Could you repost this as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted?